# arima.sim() function with varying: sample sizes, phi values and sd values

Tags: r, arima

I want to simulate `ARIMA(1,1,0)` with varying:

1. sample sizes
2. phi values
3. standard deviation values.

I admire how the bellow `r` code is simulating just one `ARIMA(1,1,0)` which I want to follow the format to simulate many `ARIMA(1,1,0)` with varying **sample sizes**, **phi values** and **standard deviation values**

```
wn <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
ar <- wn[1:2]
for (i in 3:10){
  ar<- arima.sim(n=10,model=list(ar=-0.7048,order=c(1,1,0)),start.innov=4.1,n.start=1,innov=wn)
}
```

I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825843/i-want-to-simulate-moving-average-process-of-order-one-ma1-with-varying-sample?rq=1) and given a good answer based on my question, but now I see that `arima.sim()` function is indispensable in simulating `ARIMA` time series and therefore want to incorporate it into my style of simulating `ARIMA` time series. 
I come up with this trial that uses `arima.sim()` function to simulate **N=c(15, 20)** `ARIMA(1,1,0)` time series with varying **sample sizes**, **standard deviation values** and **phi values** by first generating **N** random number and then using the initial two random number to be the first two `ARIMA(1,1,0). The 3rd to **n**th are the made to follow`ARIMA(1,1,0)`.
Here is what I have tried bellow:

```
N <- c(15L, 20L)
SD = c(1, 2) ^ 2
phi = c(0.2, 0.4)
res <- vector('list', length(N))
names(res) <- paste('N', N, sep = '_')
set.seed(123L)
for (i in seq_along(N)){
  res[[i]] <- vector('list', length(SD))
  names(res[[i]]) <- paste('SD', SD, sep = '_')
  ma <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = N[i], ncol = length(phi)) 
  for (j in seq_along(SD)){
    wn <- rnorm(N[i], mean = 0, sd = SD[j])
    ar[[1:2, ]] <- wn[[1:2]]
    for (k in 3:N[i]){
      ar[k, ] <- arima.sim(n=N[[i]],model=list(ar=phi[[k]],order=c(1,1,0)),start.innov=4.1,n.start=1,innov=wn)
    }
    colnames(ar) <- paste('ar_theta', phi, sep = '_')
    res[[i]][[j]] <- ar
  }
}
res1 <- lapply(res, function(dat) do.call(cbind,  dat))
sapply(names(res1), function(nm) write.csv(res1[[nm]], 
                                           file = paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))
```

The last two lines write the time series data in .csv and save it in my working directory.

Comment: i seriously need help

Comment: I am still waiting for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here may be a method using `Map`. Please edit your post to include expected output if this does not meet your requirements.

```
N <- c(15L, 20L)
SD <- c(1, 2) ^ 2
phi = c(0.2, 0.4)

## generate all combos
all_combos <- expand.grid(N = N, SD = SD, phi = phi)

## create function
fx_arima <- function(n, SD, phi) {
  arima.sim(n = n,
            model=list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 1, 0)),
            start.innov = 4.1,
            n.start = 1,
            rand.gen = function(n) rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = SD))[-1L]
}

## find arima for all combos using Map
set.seed(123L)
res = Map(fx_arima, all_combos[["N"]], all_combos[["SD"]], all_combos[["phi"]])

## or a little bit more work:
set.seed(123L)
res2 = by(all_combos, all_combos["N"], 
   function(DF) {
     res = mapply(fx_arima, DF[["N"]], DF[["SD"]], DF[["phi"]])
     colnames(res) = paste("SD", DF[["SD"]], "phi", DF[["phi"]], sep = "_")
     res
   })
res2

## write to csv
Map(function(file, DF) write.csv(DF, paste0("N_", file, ".csv")), names(res2), res2)
```

Comment: I hail your intelligence on this answer

Comment: I will not need elements of the first row which are 0.0000000, I will like them deleted like `ar[-1]` in my simple case.

Comment: Are you trying to say `n=N` in `rand.gen = function(n) rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = SD))`?

Comment: I also want to write the output in .csv file like I included in my question above as I will be extending the `N`, `SD` and the `phi` to something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922709/how-to-write-r-output-with-unequal-length-into-excel but the `res1 <- lapply(res, function(dat) do.call(cbind,  dat))
sapply(names(res1), function(nm) write.csv(res1[[nm]], 
                                           file = paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))` does not work

Comment: My attempt to write the output of your answer as I run `sapply(names(res), function(nm) write.csv(res[[nm]], 
                                           file = paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))
` gave me 5 different data frame of this nature `$N_50000
NULL

$N_70000
NULL

$N_100000
NULL

$N_150000
NULL

$N_200000
NULL` while the first function prints 2 data frame of 4 columns each

Comment: See edits. For ```N = c(15L, 20L)``` the output of the code above is two CSVs.