# Count with Varying Levels Parameters in R

Tags: r

I want R to count how many times my simulated `ARIMA` data conform to `ARIMA(1,0,0)` which I have achieved with:

```
library(forecast)
library(forecast)
cnt <- 0
num <- 60
phi <- 0.8

for(i in 1:10) { 
  epselon <- rnorm(num, mean=0, sd=1)
  ar1 <- arima.sim(n = num, model=list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), 
sd=1)
  ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1)
  if(all(arimaorder(ar2) == c(1, 0, 0))) cnt <- cnt + 1}
cnt
```

The above is just for a single case when `sd=1`, `n=60`, and `ar=0.8`.

I want a case when I have varying levels of `N <- c(15, 20)`, `SD <- c(1, 2) ^ 2`, and `phi = c(0.8, 0.9)` for sample size, standard diviation and `AR` parameter respectively.

I have traid this:

```
library(forecast)
N <- c(15, 20)
SD <- c(1, 2) ^ 2
phi = c(0.8, 0.9)

## generate all combos
all_combos <- expand.grid(N = N, SD = SD, phi = phi)
epselon = function(n) rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = SD)

## create function
fx_arima <- function(n, SD, phi) {
    cnt <- 0
    num <- 60
    phi <- 0.8

    for(i in 1:10) { 
      epselon <- rnorm(num, mean=0, sd=1)
      ar1 <- arima.sim(n = num, model=list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
      ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1)
      if(all(arimaorder(ar2) == c(1, 0, 0))) cnt <- cnt + 1}
    cnt
}

## find arima for all combos using Map
set.seed(123L)
res = Map(fx_arima, all_combos[["N"]], all_combos[["SD"]], 
all_combos[["phi"]])

## or a little bit more work:
set.seed(123L)
res2 = by(all_combos, all_combos["N"], 
   function(DF) {
     res = mapply(fx_arima, DF[["N"]], DF[["SD"]], DF[["phi"]])
     colnames(res) = paste("SD", DF[["SD"]], "phi", DF[["phi"]], sep = "_")
     res
   })
res2

## write to csv
Map(function(file, DF) write.csv(DF, paste0("N_", file, ".csv")), 
names(res2), res2)
```

which I mirror from [arima.sim() function with varying: sample sizes, phi values and sd values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970948/arima-sim-function-with-varying-sample-sizes-phi-values-and-sd-values) and [R Count How Many Time `auto.arima()` Confirm`arima.sim()` to be True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604878/r-count-how-many-time-auto-arima-confirmarima-sim-to-be-true/62605328#62605328)

I got this error message

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("SD_1_phi_0.2", "SD_4_phi_0.2", : attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
Traceback:
```

How can I solve this such that will have my result to show in varying form suuch that first row will be the label while the second row will be the count itself. The result will in two sheets; the first will be for 'N=15' and the second will be for 'N=20'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, the error comes from function `colnames` because your function does not return a "pure" matrix-like object. If, instead, you use the function `names` in your last chunk of code as follows:

```
res2 = by(all_combos, all_combos["N"], 
          function(DF) {
            res = mapply(fx_arima, DF[["N"]], DF[["SD"]], DF[["phi"]])
            names(res) = paste("SD", DF[["SD"]], "phi", DF[["phi"]], sep = "_")
            return(res)
          })
res2
```

You will get:

```
> res2
N: 15
SD_1_phi_0.8 SD_4_phi_0.8 SD_1_phi_0.9 SD_4_phi_0.9 
           1            3            7            5 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
N: 20
SD_1_phi_0.8 SD_4_phi_0.8 SD_1_phi_0.9 SD_4_phi_0.9 
           3            4            5            2
```

With elements accessible by name and index:

```
> res2$`15`["SD_1_phi_0.8"]
SD_1_phi_0.8 
           1 
> res2$`15`[1]
SD_1_phi_0.8 
           1
```